# Using post header variables in custom layout in Jekyll

Tags: layout, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I've to define a post like as shown which is derived from `mylayout.html`:

```
---
layout: mylayout
title:   "My Post"
varA: default
---
This post is bla bla bla ...
```

**How can i have a layout that makes use of `varA` in `mylayout.html`**?. I wish to achieve `mylayout.html` as something like following:

```
---
layout:default
---
<H1>This is {{post.varA}}</H1>

{{content}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I was using `{{post.varA}}` in layout considering it's a post variable. But, I guess inside layout it is accessed as `{{page.editorfile}}`. Using following `mylayout.html` solved this issue:

```
---
layout:default
---
<H1>This is {{page.varA}}</H1>

{{content}}
```